# Sonar Resource Not found and File Not Found

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

My project is multi-module project mixed of java and groovy classes. I have added java and groovy plugin in my sonarqube. My code is mixed of java and groovy classes. For testing, i have used junit and spock framework. Test classes are mixed of java and groovy.
I am using gradle as build tool. While i execute `gradle sonarqube` its giving below warnings.

`Resource not found: com.abc.xyz.testclass` - test class

`File not found: com.abc.class` - classes

I have added below sonarqube config in gradle

```
        sonarqube {
    properties {
    property "sonar.host.url", "sonar url"
    property "sonar.login", "loging token"
    property "sonar.projectKey", "project key"
    property "sonar.projectName", "project name"
    property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"
    property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath",               "${project.buildDir}/jacoco/jacocoTest.exec"
    property "sonar.junit.reportPaths", "${project.buildDir}/test-results/test"
    property "sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "jacoco"
    property "sonar.groovy.binaries", "${project.buildDir}/classes/groovy/main,${project.buildDir}/classes/groovy/scripts"
    property "sonar.java.binaries", "${project.buildDir}/classes/groovy/main,${project.buildDir}/classes/groovy/scripts,${project.buildDir}/classes/java/main"
    property "sonar.java.test.binaries", "${project.buildDir}/classes/groovy/test"
    property "sonar.groovy.test.binaries", "${project.buildDir}/classes/groovy/test"
    }
    }
```

BTW Its uploading analysis on sonarqube server.
gradle task is completing successfully.
please help me in removing these warnings.

Comment: I'm have the same setup and am seeing the same things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the "Resource not found" piece of the puzzle...

My project's production code is written in Java, while our unit tests are written in both Java (JUnit) and Groovy (Spock). As best as I can tell, SonarQube analyzes Java first, and spits out a "Resource not found: ..." message for each Groovy/Spock unit test. Then, it analyzes Groovy and spits out a "Resource not found: ..." message for each Java/JUnit unit test.

I think that makes sense.